# Wrap State result in a Just

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I have a Haskell function in my Prolog interpreter assignment that reads

```
renames :: Rule -> State ExecState [(Term, Term)]
```

which produces (almost) a substitution of variables in a Prolog rule (so that variable names don't clash during unification).

The pairs produced by this function are of the form `(Variable "X", Variable "X_11")`, meaning that the variable *X* should be renamed to *X_11*, etc. (the counter for the renames is contained within `ExecState`).

The problem is that I've defined a substitution to be

```
type Subst = Maybe [(Term, Term)]
```

and that makes sense, because sometimes a substitution cannot be found which unifies two terms. (But the substitution to rename variables is always found.)

I have tried

```
renames' :: Rule -> State ExecState Subst
renames' rule = Just $ renames rule
```

but that won't work, obviously, because I wrap the `State` in the `Just`, not the computation result.

How do I wrap the actual `[(Term, Term)]` result in the `Just`? And is there a name to what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `Just <$> renames rule` work?

Comment: Well, it does :). How could I have missed `<$>`? Thanks, @Ryan! If you go through the trouble of posting that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: You might want to change the definition of `Subst` to `type Subst = [(Term, Term)]` and then use `Maybe Subst` on the operations that can fail to produce a substitution, now that you’ve discovered a case where `Subst` doesn’t need the `Maybe` wrapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Just <$> renames rule`, where the `<$>` operation is [`fmap`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/The_Functor_class).